# Java - Sending Object through Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I need some help figuring out what's going on. When I send an object through a socket, one of the properties sometimes comes through as empty, but other other properties are fine.

```
public class ItsYourTurnInfo extends ServerInfo {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String  testString;
    private Hand    hand;
    private Suit    suitLead;

    public ItsYourTurnInfo(Hand hand, Suit suitLead, String testString) {
        this.hand = hand;
        this.suitLead = suitLead;
        this.testString = testString;
        System.out.println("It's your turn, hand size: " + this.hand.getSize());
        System.out.println("Test String 1: " + testString);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(GameFrame gameFrame) {
        System.out.println("It's your turn, hand size again: "+ this.hand.getSize());
        System.out.println("Leading Suit: " + this.suitLead);
        System.out.println("Test String 2: " + this.testString);
        CardsPanel panel = gameFrame.getCardsPanel();
        panel.updateHand(this.hand, this.suitLead);
    }
}
```

The results I'm getting are:

```
It's your turn, hand size: 29
Test String 1: This is just a test
It's your turn, hand size again: 0
Leading Suit: Warriors
Test String 2: This is just a test
```

Sometimes, the 3rd line will read "It's your turn, hand size again: 29"
The code I'm using to run this is in a Thread, but I don't think that's causing the problem:

```
class PlayGame extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        dealCards();

        Player p = players.get(0);
        System.out.println("Player hand size: " + p.getHand().getSize());
        p.write(new ItsYourTurnInfo(p.getHand(), Suit.WARRIORS, "This is just a test"));

        while (!gameOver && players.size() > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* Do nothing */
            }
        }
        close();
    }
}
```

The Hand class is serialized (as is ServerInfo, which ItsYourTurnInfo extends).

Also, I'm running this on a single computer for testing at this time. It has not been tried over a physical network.
Only the Hand property is affected (sometimes has cards, sometimes does not), and I cannot understand why. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Can you show us the code for serializing the `Hand` class?

Comment: The fact that you use multiple threads might well be the problem. Unless you declared the members of `Player` as `volatile` there is no guarantee your executing thread sees a current copy of your player instance variables.

Comment: i don't know but try to add synchronized to the getter of size in hand may be access is quicker than writing in some cases assuming that you are using start for lunching the threads !!!

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The code for the Hand class, I got from here: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/chapter5/Hand.java  The only change I made was to have it implement Serializable

Comment: @Ralf: I did add volatile to the properties of the Player class, as well as to the Hand class just in case.  It seems now that as long as there's only 1 player data gets transmitted properly. But as soon as I add a second player, it's up to the same old tricks. 
I'm not sure where, but I'm going to look elsewhere to see if the info's getting removed or something.

Comment: I recommend you try to get it to work single-threaded first. Once it works, add back the multi-threading.

Comment: @Ralf: Thanks. I did find a fix for it; which is to copy the Hand property to another variable and send that. I know it's wrong, but I'm going to use that until I get a bit more experience under my belt. I'm not sure how to effectively have 4 computers connected together with sockets and not use multi-threading.
Thanks again for the help.